# SSL issues on my website

Tags: https, security-certificate

I'm running a XenForo website and I am now getting SSL security issues.  I'm not so experienced in SSL, so I'm hoping you guys can provide some clarity on them.

I was thinking that they probably had something to do with CHMOD, but don't know enough about it to help.

Here is a screenshot indicating the issues:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are loading external content like the Facebook like button from an external non-HTTPS location, therefore you're getting this error message. It is not the server or your page itself which is the problem, the problem is with the external content you are linking to.

If you want to fix those errors as well, then you would have to connect to all the external services (like Twitter and Facebook, etc...) over HTTPS as well.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: You have to search on each of these websites for the correct URL. E.g here is the documentation for the Facebook Like Button: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/ As a side note: The tool you used to check the SSL connection gave you more warnings than it should. The problem you have here is actually not a problem. It is just something that could be done better.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen your screenshot. First URL is: `<pre>http://yourdomain/yourdirectory/etc/sits_small.png</pre>`.

I suggest you to keep all your images, JavaScript and CSS files with protocol HTTPS.

Comment: Welcome on Pro Webmasters! Could you explain to TaylorTDHouse why using HTTPS for images, JavaScript and CSS files is your suggestion?

Comment: Thank you.Because it means images,javascript and css calling from same protocol.